# How to limit includes on a belongsToMany association in Sequelize JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I currently have the following models in Sequelize:

`Product`

and

```
ProductList.belongsToMany(models.Product, { as: 'products', through: 
sequelize.models.ProductListProduct, foreignKey: 'productListId'});
```

and the pivot, `ProductListProduct`

I am currently trying to get a series of `productList` to show on my homepage,

and would need to limit the returned products to a certain value (6 in this case):

```
let productLists = await ProductList.findAll({
        where: {
            slug: ['recommended', 'new_and_promos']
        },
        include: [{
            model: Product,
            as: 'products',
            include: ['attributes', 'images'],
            where: {
                active: true
            }
        }],
        order: [
            [
                'products', ProductListProduct, 'position', 'ASC'
            ]
        ]
    })
```

This is the current fetch, however if I add a limit to the include, it tells me that only hasMany can have `{separate: true}` ;

To recap, what I'm trying to achieve is to return n ProductList, each with just m Product attached.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working like this, doesn't look ideal but it does the job:

```
let productLists = await ProductList.findAll({
            where: {
                slug: ['recommended', 'new_and_promos']
            },
            include: [{
                model: Product,
                as: 'products',
                include: ['attributes', 'images'],
                where: Sequelize.literal('`products->ProductListProduct`.`position` < 8')
            }],
            order: [
                [
                    'products', ProductListProduct, 'position', 'ASC'
                ]
            ]
        })
```